# Black screen on login manager Kubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10

I'm using Kubuntu 17.10

It worked fine but after an upgrade when I try to login in login manager a black screen showed then I back to login manager

When I enter wrong password it says me "Login Failed" but with correct password black screen came

I try upgrading my all packages in single mode but even it doesnt work

Please help me

Comment: Have you checked this: https://askubuntu.com/a/363238/248467

Comment: @ManishKumarBisht it just back to login screen

Comment: Something you might want to try is to create a new user and see if you can login properly as that user.  (i.e., Use Ctrl + Alt + F1 to open a non-graphical terminal, then create that user)  If you can, then it means there is a problem with your settings in your home directory.  If you still cannot, then there's a problem with your upgrade.  If it is the latter, do you use proprietary graphics drivers like NVidia?  Make sure you update those, too.

Comment: Thanks Ray. I create a new user and it login without problem. Then I check /etc/passwd and see my old user try to use zsh az default shell but zsh doesnt install on my ubuntu. I change default shell to Bash and it worked!